# When creating an R package how do I include warnings that display upon installation? Is there a convenient roxygen2 tag?

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2, deprecation-warning

I am packaging up some of the functions used by my company regularly. I would like to include warnings in the package that display upon installation/update notifying colleagues of changes that may have downstream effects on their code? Is there a roxgen2 tag I could use in the package documentation?

Comment: I'd suggest including `warnign()` in the functions that have this changes, because a) who pays attention to installation messages as long as there is no error ;) and b) it's not always the same person installing the package and using it...(Edit: On second thought: That could be really annoying... maybe not a good suggestion.. sorry) Alternatively, I'*think* you could use `packageStartupMessage("WARNING")` and it should be displayed after calling `library` (never used it myself)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such tag for `package:roxygen2`.

But you can edit the function(s) directly.  Here is what `RPushBullet` does (in the context of parsing a config file).

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    dotfile <- .getDotfile()                                    
    if (file.exists(dotfile)) .parseResourceFile(dotfile)       
}

.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    packageStartupMessage("Attaching RPushbullet version ",
                          packageDescription("RPushbullet")$Version, ".")
    dotfile <- .getDotfile()
    if (file.exists(dotfile)) {
        packageStartupMessage("Reading ", dotfile)
        .parseResourceFile(dotfile)
    } else {
        txt <- paste("No file", dotfile, "found. Consider placing the",
                     "Pushbullet API key and your device id(s) there.")
        txt <- paste(strwrap(txt), collapse="\n")
        packageStartupMessage(txt)
        .pkgenv[["pb"]] <- NULL                     
    }
}
```

So `.onLoad()` is actually not allowed to print messages, but `.onAttach()`. As it is more polite to display them in a way *that is also suppressable* you should not use `cat()` or `warning()` directly but `packageStartupMessage()`.

These are commonly placed in a file `R/init.R` or `R/zzz.R`.